# how to create a dropdown to filter data on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to Ruby on Rails (4.0), and I'm struggling to find the best way forward for something I'm attempting to implement. I've been searching for a while and find myself getting even more confused. At its core, I'd like to have a homepage that lets a user have a dropdown populated by my Requirements model, and when the user clicks on a Requirements.title, only those rows with the same title to be displayed. Right now I have the following:

**_req_dropdown.html.erb**

```
<div id="category_select">
  <%= collection_select(:requirement, :id, Requirement.all, :id, :title, options={:prompt => "Select a requirement"}, html_options={:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'} ) %>
</div>
```

**_req_item.html.erb**

```
<ol id="<%= req_item.id %>">
  <span class="req_num">R<%= req_item.req_num %></span>
  <span class="title"><%= req_item.title %></span>
  <span class="description"><%= req_item.description %></span>
</ol>
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @requirement = current_user.requirements.build
      @req_items = current_user.req_list.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end    
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def req_list
    Requirement.where("user_id = ? ", id)
  end
```

What's the best way to implement a homepage that uses a dropdown to filter data? Any suggestions would be great, and let me know if I haven't added enough info

Comment: It seems you're using `Requirement.all` instead of using `@req_items`. That would be a starting point. I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: Are you expecting filter your page table row's data, based on selected dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ajax and replacing expected div with new data. I am explaining small code snippet, I hope it will help you.

1. Load your default page, As there will not be any filter at first point.
2. Select drop down- Fire ajax call on change event and get new data from db.

   ```
   = select_tag('new_data', options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard", "Discover" ], ["VISA", "Discover"])

   // replace below div
   .replace_me
   ```

Ajax call

```
// searching the kids when session alone changes

$('#new_data').live('change', function() { 
  searching_new_data()     
}).change();

function searching_new_data()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "/controller/methods",
    data: { new_data: $('#new_data').val(){
      $("#form_loading").show(); 
    },              
    complete: function(){  
      $('#form_loading').hide();

    },        
    success: function(html){ 
      $('#form_loading').hide();    
      $('#loading').empty();
      $('#loading').append(html);
    }
  })
}
```

controller:

```
def new_data
  // query logic will goes here
end
```

View:

```
// replaced view code
_new_data.html.haml
```

It's brief flow of your requirement.